# Как связать нажатие клавиши на клавиатуре с JButton?

Tags: java, swing, gui, listener

Какой нужно использовать метод для "нажатия" кнопки в программе, после нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре?

Comment: Существует ли вообще такой метод? :)

Comment: Хотите реализовать "горячие клавиши"?

Comment: @Streletz не хочу копировать и переделывать методы, использующие в параметре 
ActionEvent на KeyEvent

Comment: может быть в сторону [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) посмотреть?